# How to convert a letter to lowercase after a quotation mark?

Tags: python, lowercase

How to convert a letter to lowercase which is in a string after a quotation mark?

Like this:

```
"Trees Are Never Sad Look At Them Every Once In Awhile They'Re Quite Beautiful."
```

should become

```
"Trees Are Never Sad Look At Them Every Once In Awhile They're Quite Beautiful."
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.sub` with a callback function we can try:

```py
import re

inp = "Trees Are Never Sad Look At Them Every Once In Awhile They'Re Quite Beautiful."
output = re.sub(r"'([A-Z])", lambda m: "'" + m.group(1).lower(), inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

> Trees Are Never Sad Look At Them Every Once In Awhile They're Quite Beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the string and then find the character of the apostrophe. Then replace the upper case letter with lowercase letter following the apostrophe:

```
string = "Trees Are Never Sad Look At Them Every Once In Awhile They'Re Quite Beautiful."

for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i] == "'": # Check for apostrophe
        string = string.replace(string[i+1], string[i+1].lower()) # Make the character followed by apostrophe lower case by replacing uppercase letter.
print(string)
```

Output:

```
Trees Are Never Sad Look At Them Every Once In Awhile They're Quite Beautiful.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do so using `join()`:

```
data = "Trees Are Never Sad Look At Them Every Once In Awhile They'Re Quite Beautiful."

new_data = "".join(char.lower() if i and data[i-1] == "'" else char for i, char in enumerate(data))
print(new_data)  # Trees Are Never Sad Look At Them Every Once In Awhile They're Quite Beautiful.
```

---

### Explanation

- We use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate over each character in the string, knowing its index.
- For each character, we check if the previous one is `'` using `data[i-1] == "'"`.
- We also check that it is not the first character of the string, in which case `data[i-1]` would correspond to the last letter of the string (`data[-1]`).

We therefore convert the character to lowercase only if the two conditions are met:

- `i != 0`, it can also be written `if i`, because an integer evaluates to `True` only if it is non-zero.
- `data[i-1] == "'"`

Comment: In this `if i and data[i-1]` why i is used..can you pls explain?

Comment: @logi I tried to elaborate the answer.

Comment: Thx for the detailed explanation..